# Set selected value on edit in Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

i need to get selected value on select tag on edit.

i have form select field like this.

```
<%= f.select :city,  options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, 'id', 'name',@city),{}, {:class=>'form-control',:'data-validation'=>"required",:'data-validation-error-m‌​sg'=>"Select City"} %>
```

in my controller on edit i did like this:

```
def edit
 @cities=City.all
 @p = Property.find(params[:id])
 @city=@p.city
end
```

when i try to print like this `<%= @city %>` in my *edit form* , it is getting the selected value from database. But when i try to give in select field it is not reflecting. Please help.

Any help is appreciatable

Comment: **bt when i try to give in select field it is not reflecting** - could you please explain it bit more. Its unclear what you want to reflect and where ?

Comment: value is coming correct when i just print but in select box its not showing that is selected .

Comment: just try it `options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, 'id', 'name',@city.id.to_s)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.select :city, options_for_select(@cities.collect{|city| [city.name, city.id]}, @city), :prompt => "Select One", :class => 'form-control' %>
```

Hope this helps! You can see [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) ?
Something like:

```
f.collection_select :city, :city_id, @cities, :id, :name
```

Anytime you create/edit a new object the form's builder will populate the select with the object's value (in case there is an object); this is, will set the `selected` attribute - or simply populate the select if you're creating a new object.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
<%= f.select :city,  options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, 'id', 'name',@city), {selected: @city.id}, {:class=>'form-control',:'data-validation'=>"required",:'data-validation-error-m‌​sg'=>"Select City"} %>
```

Basically, if you add {selected: @city.id} to the hash after the options_from_collection_for_select it should work. The select method is a bit funky.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved like this

```
<%= form.select :product_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Product.where(:active => true), :id, :name, item.product_id), {}, {class: "form-select"} %>
```